# Turning a Frobenius algebra into a symmetric algebra via tensor products

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, frobenius-algebras

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional Frobenius algebra over a field $K$, which means that $A \cong D(A)$ as right $A$-modules. Being symmetric means that $A \cong D(A)$ as $A$-bimodules. Here $D(-)=Hom_K(-,K)$ is the natural duality.

> Question: Is there a version of twisted tensor product $\otimes_K^t$ (which might be a generalisation of what is done in https://folk.ntnu.no/opperman/tensor.pdf) for $A$ such that $B:=A \otimes_K^t A$ is a symmetric algebra and such that we also have the formula $Ext_B^*(M \otimes_K^t N, M \otimes_K^t N)= Ext_A^*(M,N) \otimes_K^{\hat{t}} Ext_A^*(M,N)$ as in line 19 of the paper https://folk.ntnu.no/opperman/tensor.pdf ?

The assumption in this paper seem to be too strong (for example needing a grading) for this and my question is whether one can use a generalisation of the tensor product such that one obtain a symmetric algebra for $B$ and the formula for Ext still holds.
A completely different construction might also be interesting that turns $A$ into a symmetric algebra and so that the Ext formula holds.